# I have a free app that I would like to place on the Appexchange. What steps are necessary to move forward

Tags: search

I would like to place my app on the Appexchange.  My app is free.  What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article describing the steps of publishing an app on the AppExchange:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout

Shortly summarized: You will have to signup for a Salesforce Partner account. Next, you can create a Publishing Org from which you can publish your app. Before your app will actually be published, however, a security review will take place. Then, you can publish your app.